# Does apple permit background facial recognition in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, camera, appstore-approval, facial-identification

We are building an app for kids, where they can interact with animation character. We want to get camera feed while in interacting without show camera feed on UI for facial recognition. Continious accessing camera can drain battery and could have privacy issue. Does apple permit it?

[Apple review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) does not mention any related information.

Comment: There are no background modes for camera usage... so no. you cannot do it.

Comment: I think he didn't mean while the app's in background. If you want simply want the camera input while the app's active, that should work just fine

Comment: @henrik-dmg right, thank you so much. Could continue accessing be a possible cause for rejection for AppStore approval?

Comment: @ShamimHossain I think as long as you show a clear indication whenever you're using the camera, you should be good. See section 2.5.14 of App Store Review Guidelines :) https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/

Comment: @henrik-dmg thank you for you information